# Problema en el uso de fetch javascript con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

A través del método POST estoy realizando una petición a un servidor PHP, en donde en este recibo usando `$_POST`. El problema es que al parecer no llegan los valores deseados el servidor.

Mi código `JS`

```
function configureAjaxCalls(_mainFunc,_func,idSelect,idSelectA) {

const data = {
        mainFunc:_mainFunc,
        id:idSelect,
        idA:idSelectA
}

fetch('control.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body:data
 })
    .then(ajaxPositive)
    .catch(showError);

function ajaxPositive(response) {
  console.log('response.ok: ', response);
  if(response.ok) {
    response.text().then(showResult);

    switch(_func){
        case 3: 
            funcion1(data);
        break;
        case 4:
            funcion2(data);
        break;
        case 5:
            funcion3
        case 25:
            funcion4
        default:
            null; 
                }
  } else {
    showError('status code: ' + response.status);
  }
}

function showResult(txt) {
  console.log('muestro respuesta: ', txt);
}

function showError(err) { 
  console.log('muestor error', err);
}
}
```

Mi código `PHP`

```
<? 
   require_once("class.php");

       if(isset($_POST['mainFunc']))
      {

        $funcion = $_POST['mainFunc'];
        $id = $_POST['id']; 
        //echo($id);

         $npacto = $_POST['idA'];
          //echo($npacto); 

          switch($funcion) {   
               //**********************Resultados******************//

               case 'getData1';
                   $instancia = new Consulta;
                   $data_reg_result =$instancia ->query1();
                    echo($data_reg_result);
                      break;

                 case 'getData2';
                  $instancia5 = new Consulta;
                  $data_reg_result =$instancia5->query2($id);
                       echo($data_reg_result);
                    break;


                     case 'getData3';
                     $instancia6 = new Consulta;
                     $data_reg_result =$instancia6->query3($id);
                     echo($data_reg_result);
                     break;

                       case 'lista';

                         $instanciaR0 = new Consulta;
                          $data_reg_result =$instanciaR0->query4($id,$npacto);
                        echo($data_reg_result);
                          break;
                          }

                          }

           else
         {

              echo "no existe data";
           }

          ?>
```

Independiente por ahora de lo que suceda dentro del Switch, el problema no logro identificarlo y desconozco el por qué pasa directo al `echo "no existe data"`

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que PHP no puede parsear un POST en el que viene un objeto JSON enviado por fetch, por eso tu POST llega vacio, tenes que modificar tu archivo de PHP a algo como:

```php
$payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($payload, true);

# Luego incluye tus condicionales

if(isset($json->mainFunc)) {
  ...
}
```

luego en el objeto json puedes accesar a sus propiedades y seguir con tus condicionales

En el JS script estaba revisando que tenes que asegurarte de enviar los datos como objeto JSON entonces tendrias que agregar una pequeña sentencia

```javascript
const data = {
        mainFunc:_mainFunc,
        id:idSelect,
        idA:idSelectA
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

fetch('control.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: jsonData
 })
    .then(ajaxPositive)
    .catch(showError);
```

Comment: al hacer un print_r del $_POST este muestra vacío, asumo que quizás el error viene del JS, pero nose que problema puede ser

Comment: Es porque estas enviando un JSON y PHP no lo puede interpretar entonces tenes que hacer uso de "php://input" y file_get_contents para extraer el data recibido y luego convertirlo a un objeto de PHP para poder manipularlo, no tengo un recurso en Español para compartir pero puedes revisar esto en ingles https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres recibir los datos directamente en `$_POST` una buena opción es usar el [objeto FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) en lugar de JSON:

```
function configureAjaxCalls(_mainFunc, _func, idSelect, idSelectA) {
    // Crear objeto FormData
    const data = new FormData();
    // Agregar valores
    data.append('mainFunc', _mainFunc);
    data.append('id', idSelect);
    data.append('idA', idSelectA);

    // Ejecutar petición AJAX
    fetch('control.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body:data
    })
    .then(ajaxPositive)
    .catch(showError);
    // Aquí tus funciones para éxito y error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En tu PHP debes convertir a JSON tus consultas PRUEBA colocando esto de cabezera para indicar que lo que va devolver es un archivo JSON:
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

y para mostrar en el echo:

`echo json_encode($query, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: Favor explicar el por que se debe agregar el header(); mostrado en tu código; [Editar y dar formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/451023/edit) de código a tu respuesta.

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta